# Can't insert attachment in iMesageExtension if an MSStickerView is instantiated

Tags: objective-c, video, imessage-extension

I'm trying to send an mp4 video using an MSMessage from a MessageExtension.

When using the following code :

```
//Initializate an MSSticker
NSError* error = nil;
NSURL* stickerURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"image" withExtension:@"png"];
MSSticker* sticker = [[MSSticker alloc] initWithContentsOfFileURL:stickerURL localizedDescription:@"" error:&error];

//Initialize an MSStickerView
MSStickerView* stickerView = [[MSStickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 65, 65)];
stickerView.sticker = sticker;//<-- this line creates the side effect issue

//Send an attachement
NSURL* fileUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"video" withExtension:@"mp4"];
[[[MSConversation alloc] init] insertAttachment:fileUrl withAlternateFilename:nil completionHandler:^(NSError * error) {
}];
```

No error is raised, all files exist properly.
But then I get the following result :
[image: Not the video I'm expecting]

If I remove the line `stickerView.sticker = sticker;`, then everything works properly and the video is sent.

Any idea how to fix it ?